# Radius of convergence of the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdots(3n)}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find the **radius of convergence** for this series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n-1)}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot\cdot\cdot(3n)}x^n $$

Treating it as an alternating series, I got 
$$x< \dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$$

And absolute convergence tests yield
$$-\dfrac{1}{2}<x<\dfrac{1}{2}$$

I feel like it's simpler than I expect but I just can't get it. How do I do this?

**Answer in book:** $\dfrac{3}{2}$

Comment: Use ratio test.

Comment: But that's what I used to get the second range for x; however, the answer in the book is 3/2.

Comment: By the ratio test you should study $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ as $n\to+\infty$. Is that what you did? If so, please include your calculation and we'll se what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, I took the limit and got 2|x| as the result, which should be less than 1, which then leads to the second range for x in my post.

Comment: I think there is a $3$ missing in your calculation then. Don't you agree it should be $\frac{3(n+1)}{2n+1}$ where you have written $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$?

Comment: For some reason I get x (2n+1)/(n+1). I'll check jibounet's answer and compare it to mine.

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}~t^n ~=~ \frac1{\sqrt{1-2t}}.~$ In this case, $t=-\dfrac x3.~$ See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio test allows to determine the radius of convergence.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, let :

$$ a_{n} = (-1)^{n}\frac{1 \times 3 \times \ldots \times (2n-1)}{3 \times 6 \times \ldots \times (3n)}. $$

Then,

$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{\vert a_{n+1} \vert}{\vert a_{n} \vert} &= {} \frac{1 \times 3 \times \ldots \times (2n-1) \times (2n+1)}{3 \times 6 \times \ldots (3n) \times (3n+3)} \times \frac{3 \times 6 \times \ldots \times (3n)}{1 \times 3 \times \ldots \times (2n-1)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{2n+1}{3n+3} \; \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \; \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}
$$

Since the ratio $\displaystyle \frac{\vert a_{n+1} \vert}{\vert a_{n} \vert}$ converges to $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}$, we can conclude that $R = \displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I gave you a +1, but maybe the $(-1)^n$ should be indicated in one or another form?

Comment: Okay, for some reason when considering a{n+1}, I omitted the first term of each infinite product (I used 3*5*... and 6*9*..., instead of 1*3*5*... and 3*6*9...).

Comment: @mickep : Thanks for your comment. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the series as $a_n = \frac{(2n)!}{6^n n! n!} x^n$ and use ratio test: see what happens with $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| $

Comment: The ratio test is actually (slightly) easier to perform without the rewriting.